# Java coding contest NZEC error on input

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader

I'm getting an NZEC exception on a hackerearth problem. This code has just the logic to input data and still its throws exception. This happens for most the cases and for rest exception not thrown. Sample test-cases as well as few of main cases run properly with this when I add the code to handle the problem

I have tried both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` and yet no change in result. 
Also observed if I remove the `string.split()`  when using `BuffredReader` the exception goes away however obviously split is needed to parse the input.

I am complete loss what to do to get rid of this parsing issue.

```
public class JumboTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        //String line;
        //String str[]=new String[3];
        //line = br.readLine();
        //str=line.split(" ");
        //int n=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        //int c=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);

        //fill the tree as per queries
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int parent = scan.nextInt();
            int child = scan.nextInt();
            //line = br.readLine();

            //str=line.split(" ");
            //int parent=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            //int child=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        }

        //Work on queries
        //line = br.readLine();
        //str=line.split(" ");
        //int q=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        //c=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        int q = scan.nextInt();
        c = scan.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        {
            int op = scan.nextInt();
            int in = scan.nextInt();
            int val = scan.nextInt();
            //line = br.readLine();
            //str=line.split(" ");
            //op=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            //in=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
            //val=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you with debugging your code unless you share the exception message and (full) stacktrace with us.  We also need to see the specific inputs that cause the problem.

Comment: If this is part of a contest, are you actually allowed to ask others for help?